# How Scale text to parent div plugin problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5boilerplate

I've been trying to make this script work for an hour with zero luck.

Heres the proper jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zachleat/WzN6d/

Here's my website where the broke code is:
http://designobvio.us/dov2/index.html

I'm totally novice with javascript/jQuery.  Please forgive me if this is a retarded semantics problem.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `document.ready` try adding the following.

```
$(function(){
    $('#bigtext').bigtext();
});
```

jsfiddle does this for you automatically, thats why you don't need it there.

Comment: For what it's worth, it should also fix it to move the $('#bigtext').bigtext(); below your bigtext script include. Granted Loktar's solution is the right one.